# How to get access an image with its src?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am making AJAX call on the button click and in response, I am getting some image sources from the database. These images are already defined in my HTML page now I want that the sources got from the database, the images with those sources should change their background-color

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'php/retrievetime.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: {
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    async: false,
    random: random
  },
  success: function(response) {
    var objs = JSON.parse(response);
    if (objs != '') {
      $.each(objs, function(i, item) {
        var images = document.querySelector('tbody').querySelectorAll('img');
        for (let img of images) {
          var abc = img.getAttribute('src');
          if (abc = objs[i].pic1)
            img.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.29)';;
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `abc=objs[i].pic1` that is setting abc, not comparing it

Comment: Tell me the best solution for it

Comment: use a comparison operator?

Comment: `async : false` == bad idea.

Comment: @LeeTaylor That's in the `data`, so it doesn't matter. Why it's in the `data` is a different question... :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ah, yes. Odd.

Comment: @LeeTaylor can u tell me disadvantage of async:false ?

Comment: You could save yourself some looping by querying for the specific image: `const image = document.querySelector(`tbody img[src="${objs[i].pic1}"]`);` check for null, then `image.style.back...`

Comment: @مہرعمرغفار That setting is inside `data`, perhaps that's where you want it. But it's not affecting the ajax call in the way it would if it were outside `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the condition within the if statement to be a condition.

```
if(abc === objs[i].pic1)
```